# is there any difference between a method that takes long time to execute and the setTimeout function?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, callstack

I am learning javascript. I have a doubt. I heard that when we use the setTimeout method, javascript will remove the callback function of that setTimeout from the call stack and put it on another call stack and continue executing the current call stack.

```
function f1() {
  console.log("print first");
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("print in time out");
  }, 4000);
  console.log("print last");

}
```

The output of this function

print first
print last
print in time out

Because the callback of setTimeOut placed into a new stack.

What if I use Ajax request or something like that takes some time to execute without using async. Something like this.

```
function API(){
    const apiCALL = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    console.log(apiCALL);
}
```

is this also put into another call stack?

Comment: What exactly is a "method that takes a long time to execute"? Something like `while (true) {}`? Or an AJAX request or something like that?

Comment: Yes Something like AJAX sir

Comment: The `API` function will end executing immediately and log nothing of interest. `fetch` is returning a promise, and to get the promise result you need to add a `.then` callback to it. At which point it'll behave the same as the `setTimeout` case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you have to know it's that both `fetch` and `setTimeout` functions are not really a functions of javascript. They belong to Window - Web Apis. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

And whenever you are using those functions they go of the call stack and into a window api that is written in probably in C# or something. Once they are done doing what they are suppose to do, they send back response inside a callback queue, which u can imagine as a different call stack.

Javascript itself is single threaded but with functions from window api it can be run async.